# Is there a tool to clean up Wikipedia articles where there are duplicate references?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki

Sometimes when editing Wikipedia I find an article where references have been duplicated.

Is there a tool that makes it easy to merge all those references to the same url into just one reference?

Here is an example page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=David_Green_(social_entrepreneur)&oldid=936659277

You can see in the example that the same schwabfoundation page has multiple references to it.

Comment: Can't add an answer but you're looking for [User:Kaniivel/Reference Organizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Kaniivel/Reference_Organizer) or alternatively can try [User:Uglemat/RefMan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Uglemat/RefMan). More options available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:User_scripts/List#References_2).

Answer (score 1):

I went on the wikipedia-en-help IRC and asked.

Someone suggested using [Refill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Zhaofeng_Li/reFill#To_use_reFill_yourself) as a solution and it worked quite well but is exceptionally slow so I hope to find an alternative.

Comment: Instead of answering it is better to add this to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a tool for this purpose, but it can only do *exact match* on [`<ref>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Footnotes#WP:NAMEDREFS) tags (at least for now). It's not smart enough to detect, for example, two different references having say 90% similarity. Another thing is that it's still a *local program*, which means you need [Python 3.8+](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/) in order run it. Anyway here's the link and screenshot:

https://github.com/davidhcefx/Wikipedia-Duplicated-Citations-Merger

[image: screenshot]